# problem with logging into the application with django

Tags: django-login

I'm trying to get users authenticated is there anyone that could possibly give me some in-site as to what I am doing wrong? I've used the documentation from django an I believe i got the code as it is meant to be but when I sign out of the application the login functionality seems to be broken. I am however able to login through the admin site with the same user credentials.

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist.')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect ('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view the updated code below and read the comments I left in it:

```
def loginPage(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
          username = request.POST.get('username')
          password = request.POST.get('password')

          try:
               user = User.objects.get(username=username)
               
               # Would recommend having the below in side here: the try block. Why?
               # Because just in case a user is not found, you won't have to waste time calling the authenticate method outside.

               # Also, I'd suggest removing the request from the authenticate method as it's not a required parameter
               # user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
               user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

               if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect ('home')
               else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')
          except:
               messages.error(request, 'User does not exist.')
    
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

Let me know if that work.